# Removing textbox focus border but keeping original in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

this is my first time using WPF and I want to know how I can remove the focus border because it is overlapping my current border? I have a white border (bottom only) and I want that to stay.. but I don't want a blue border on selecting the textbox because it overlaps my text box's current border, how can I solve this?

```
<Window ResizeMode="NoResize" x:Name="Sahara" x:Class="Sahara.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sahara"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Sahara" Height="499.75" Width="696.525" Background="White" Topmost="True" Icon="C:\Users\ashle\Downloads\Seanau-Support-Bubble-Support-Bubble-1.ico">
    <Grid x:Name="Sahara1" Background="#FF6F5499">
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Sign In" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="283,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="29.333" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Verdana Pro Light"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="loginUsernameText" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="216,177,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Background="#FF926FB4" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="White" FontStyle="Italic" TextChanged="loginUsernameText_TextChanged"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="loginPasswordText" PasswordChar="•"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="216,213,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Background="#FF926FB4" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="White"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Height="30" Background="White" Foreground="#FF6F5499"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create ControlTemplate for your TextBox
something like this

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```